# Insert Python dict into Redshfit column of type Super with psycopg2

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Inserting the dictionary as a Json string without JSON_PARSE "worked" but then the column contains a string and I can't access the individual attributes like 'testdict' inside the column.
I am trying to do something like this but only find documentation on how to accomplish this via pandas:

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
    cursor,
    """
        INSERT INTO schema.table (
            id,
            col2,
            json_col
        ) 
        VALUES %s
    """,
    [(1,2,json.dumps({'testdict': 'foobar'}))],
    template=(%s, %s, JSON_PARSE(%s)),
    page_size=800,
)
```

Comment: You just need to read [psycopg2 JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was pretty close to a solution already.

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
    cursor,
    """
        INSERT INTO schema.table (
            id,
            col2,
            json_col
        ) 
        VALUES %s
    """,
    [(1,2,json.dumps({'testdict': 'foobar'}))],
    template=(%s, %s, JSON_PARSE(%s)::SUPER),
    page_size=800,
)
```